# scanf and printf just skips after 1st time

Tags: c

what is the problem here? scanf doesnt seems to working in while loop. i was trying to find out vowel & consonent until user wants.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char x,c;
    do
    {
        printf("enter\n");
        scanf("%c",&x);
        if(x=='a'||x=='e'||x=='i'||x=='o'||x=='u')
            printf("vowel\n");
        else
            printf("consonent\n");

        printf("do u want to continue ?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if(c=='n')
            printf("thnks\n");

    } while(c=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);` then go through the string character-by-character?

Comment: your OS is not delivering one character at a time - it's delivering the character typed and then it's version of <ENTER> (cr, cr/lf, lf)

Comment: @H2CO3 - probably because (s)he wants to enter one character at a time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanf() is getting skipped] (and many, many, many, many more) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413527/scanf-is-getting-skipped)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - ? - I don't understand your comment

Comment: FOR **OP**:  You changed his source of your question and corrected after getting the answer. that confuses people. Don't do this. I revert back to `%d` in `scanf()` that was an error.

Comment: I don't have an answer here and my edit of the duplicate comment has to do with the fact that the OP did zero due diligence to find the answer to his question.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry actually it was for OP. your name also start with *K* so I wrong taged :P

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry ...my mistake :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with this code to run the loop multiple times.

EDIT: Different solution without `fflush(stdin)`. Please define a string of 8 characters as

```
char str[8];
```

and modify the code in the loop as

```
fgets(str, 8, stdin); // To read the newline character
printf("do u want to continue ?(y/n)\n");

scanf("%c",&c);
fgets(str, 8, stdin); // To read the newline character
```

Comment: tried but it prints consonant and just then y/n. does not takes input 1st.

Comment: You would require 2 flushes for eliminating the 2 enter keys. I have tried this code and it seems to be functional.

Comment: @KothaAhsan did it work with the new code or still facing some issues?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined.

Comment: @Shahbaz `fflush` is a standard method to flush a given file pointer. `stdin` is the standard input file pointer. Hence, I am not sure if I got your comment correct.

Comment: @Ganesh See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin (it also doesn't work on any of the three platforms I use at work)

Comment: @Ganesh you probably wanted to write `stdout` but made mistake correct it. Cubbi's link is helpful. learn and update your answer better.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The idea was to flush the input, specifically the new line character. I referred to Cubbi's link and have updated the answer. From my understanding, `fflush` on streams opened for `reading` depends on the specific library implementation. In either case, the solution is not dependent on `fflush` anymore.

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks for the link. I tested on MSDN and MingW and found it to be working. I have updated my answer not to use `fflush`.

Comment: Flushing the input is not a good idea. You _think_ you are removing the line already read, but that's not always the case. For example, if you redirect a file to your input, you throw _everything_ away. The proper way is something like `int c; do { c = fgetc(stdin); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);`. This is besides the point that formally, the C standard says that `fflush` on input streams is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ganesh, by the way, your edit now is also not good. `gets` is a terribly unsafe function. It is deprecated by all standards (even removed from C11). You should use `fgets` instead. Nevertheless, you still need a loop, since `fgets` may not consume the whole line. The simple loop I wrote above is the easiest and safest solution I have come up with so far.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to read a character using `%d` which is wrong. Use `%c` instead.

Comment: fixed. actually i was trying to modifying using int and char when prompting for y/n. thanks for your input. still doent works afer 1st time.

Comment: I believe you may have a problem because you enter a newline character after the symbol in this scanf. Try debugging or printing the value of c in the second and consequent cycle iterations.

Comment: wait..what is error not understood his both scanfs are correct.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan he changed his source after I posted the answer

Comment: I made change again in question.

Answer (score 2):

Change code to `scanf("%c",&c)` your original code is getting the y/n entries as digits not characters

Edit:

Probably you are getting the carage return instead of the character try using `getc` or `fgets` instead and get the first character.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&c)` will take care of endlines (and all other whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be here:
        scanf("%d",&c);
It should be:

```
    scanf("%c",&c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x,c;
    do
    {
        printf("enter\n");
        scanf("%c",&x);
        getchar(); //to remove the \n from the buffer
        if(x=='a'||x=='e'||x=='i'||x=='o'||x=='u')
            printf("vowel\n");
        else
            printf("consonent\n");
        printf("do u want to continue ?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%c",&c); //Here you were using %d instead of %c
        getchar(); //to remove the \n from the buffer

        if(c=='n')
            printf("thnks\n");
    }while(c=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if cr/lf is returned for <ENTER> key?

Comment: It is generally better to explain the problem / hint the solution rather than just give it away. Especially in case of simple questions like this which are generated by beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Both scanfs should be changed like this:

```
scanf(" %c",&x);
```

...

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Note the space before the `%`, it's important: it consumes leading whitespace, which includes the endline characters left over in `stdin` after processing the input.